# How can I get displayed date of a Calendar view in Day mode via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, calendar, view

I have a custom calendar list with Calendar view, when adding a new list item I want to set Date field to the clicked date. Or even a date range

Is there a simple way to achieve this? I there a way to get current clicked datetime or at least displayed day view client JavaScript?

Comment: Any reason you can't use the actual calendar view and customize that instead of building your own? The built-in calendar already does what you're describing.

Comment: @John-M What do you mean by "use the actual calendar"? I DO use builtin Calendar list template and Calendar view, but the StartDate field is not populated with clicked date.

Comment: You said it's a "custom calendar" list, so I wanted to check if you were using the built-in calendar list template or if you created your own list and gave it a calendar view. What version of SharePoint are you using? SharePoint Online Calendar lists do automatically populate the date and time field for creating new items

Comment: @John-M yeah, I've customized my list in Visual studio - I used the same columns from the Calendar template but without some unneeded columns, the list has 106 template id. I use SP 2013